# Buffer Overflow - Not enough space for shellcode

Tags: reverse-engineering, buffer-overflow, exploit

I have exercise of Buffer Overflow. After some fuzzing, I successfully crash the application and overwrite the exact 4 bytes of EIP, then I success to jmp to ESP that holds some of my payload (the start of the payload 40 bytes, also I noticed that EBP also link to my other part of the payload but also this part is 40 bytes (I successfully can redirect the flow to the shellcode part of EBP).

I tried to run egg-hunter but because its windows x64, the hunter shellcode is 46 bytes length so it cannot run with the 40 bytes space that I have, also I didn't find any indication of my rest of the buffer that the hunter will find it.

Some information about the buffer
buffer = "A" * 7 + ret + "^" + "B" * 1000 (only 40 usable)

- I can replace the "B" location in the buffer with "^" but the same proble exist
- "^" is the symbol that cause the crash
- eip overwrite after 7 bytes
- B is the rest of the payload but only 40 bytes usable, the rest are just cutoff
- buffer = "A" * 7 + ret + **here I can also able to put 40 bytes** + "^" + "B" * 1000, I tried it with egg hunter and its works but still I have landed for little buffer and the same problem..
  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `JMP EBP` at the end of the first part if you know the the second part is pointed to by `EBP`? side question: is your stack really executable?

Comment: Hi, I can jmp to EBP with pushing to esp, but EBP also pointed to the beginning of the payload. Yest the stack executable. I will now edit the post with more information about the buffer.